# Change of basis matrix represented by linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider the basis $\alpha=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$.

Suppose now that we have a vector $a$ which is expressed as coordinate
vectors in respect to $\alpha=[a]_{\alpha}.$

The vector $[a]_{e}=\lambda_{1}v_{1}+,...,+\lambda_{n}v_{n}=\begin{pmatrix}\\
v_{1} & ... & v_{n}\\
\\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{1}\\
...\\
\lambda_{n}
\end{pmatrix}$

Where $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_{1}\\
...\\
\lambda_{n}
\end{pmatrix}=[a]_{\alpha}$ = the coordinate vector of $a$ wrt $\alpha$.

$\begin{pmatrix}\\
v_{1} & ... & v_{n}\\
\\
\end{pmatrix}=C_{\alpha}^{E}$ is simply the basis that we would like to convert from in columns
(to $E$)

So the change of basis matrix to the canonical basis is simply the
old basis in columns.

So $[a]_{E}=C_{\alpha}^{E}[a]_{\alpha}\implies[a]_{\alpha}=(C_{\alpha}^{E})^{-1}[a]_{E}=C_{E}^{\alpha}[a]_{E}$,
so to go from the canonical basis to our desired basis, we multiply
by the inverse of the change of basis matrix.

Suppose then we want to transform $[a]_{\alpha}\to[a]_{\beta}$

Sequentially it is $\underbrace{[a]_{\alpha}\to[a]_{E}}_{C_{\alpha}^{E}[a]_{\alpha}}$.
$\underbrace{[a]_{E}\to[a]_{\beta}}_{(D_{\beta}^{E})^{-1}C_{\alpha}^{E}[a]_{\alpha}=D_{E}^{\beta}C_{\alpha}^{E}[a]_{\alpha}}$

So $[a]_{\beta}=(D_{\beta}^{E})^{-1}C_{\alpha}^{E}[a]_{\alpha}$

In terms of maps:

$[a]_{\beta}=((\phi_{\beta}^{E})^{-1}\circ\phi_{\alpha}^{E})([a]_{\alpha})$,
which reading from right to left, makes sense.

So the change of basis map from $\alpha\to\beta$ is $(\phi_{\beta}^{E})^{-1}\circ\phi_{\alpha}^{E}$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.  A notation often found in introductory linear algebra texts is to write $P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha}$ for the change-of-basis matrix that has two properties:

- The columns of $P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha}$ are the $\alpha$ basis vectors expressed in the $\beta$ basis, and
- $P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha}$ converts from $\alpha$ coordinates to $\beta$ coordinates in the sense that for every vector $v$, we have $[v]_\beta = P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha} [v]_{\alpha}$

Your last equation then follows from the facts that $P_{\gamma \leftarrow \beta} P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha} = P_{\gamma \leftarrow \alpha}$ and $P_{\alpha \leftarrow \beta} = \left( P_{\beta \leftarrow \alpha} \right)^{-1}$.

Comment: In your last sentence where did you obtain the basis $\gamma$?

Comment: This was just to illustrate how the matrices combine under a composition of changes of bases.  To combine with your notation: $\left( \phi^E_{\beta} \right)^{-1} = \phi^{\beta}_E$ and $\left( \phi^E_{\beta} \right)^{-1} \circ \phi^E_{\alpha} = \phi^{\beta}_E \circ \phi^E_{\alpha} = \phi^{\beta}_{\alpha}$ since $\phi^{\beta}_{\gamma} \circ \phi^{\gamma}_{\alpha} = \phi^{\beta}_{\alpha}$ for any basis $\gamma$, not just $E$.